# How do I remove the first array inside of a nested array with ruby on rails?

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, multidimensional-array

let's say I have a nested array like so

```
array = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
```

How would I remove the very first array in the nested array so it could end up like so

```
array = [[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

Comment: Do you need to first detect if it is an array or not, or is it always an array?

Comment: while mechnicov and  Cary Swoveland point out many possible solutions, I think Farhad Ajaz's  solution is the most strait forward.  That being said,  a simple google search of "ruby remove first element from array" would yield many solutions, including those found on this site, which might result in a the question being marked as a duplicate

Answer (score 3):

you can try the following method

```
array.drop(1)
```

Comment: Note that `drop` doesn't modify `array`. (as requested by the OP)

Answer (score 3):

There are many-many ways to do it

```
array = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

You can mutate array in place with such methods

```
# Array#delete_at

array.delete_at(0)
array # => [[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

```
# Array#slice!

array.slice!(0)
array # => [[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

```
# Array#shift

array.shift # or array.shift(1)
array # => [[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

or you can assign new value

```
# Array#drop

array = array.drop(1)
```

```
# Array#[]

array = array[1..]
```

or replace content to save link to object

```
# Array#replace

array.replace(array[1..-1]) # new array as argument of replace
```

or more difficult ways

```
# Array#reject

array = array.reject!.with_index { |_, index| index.zero? }
```

```
# Array#reject!

array.reject!.with_index { |_, index| index.zero? }
```

```
# Array#select

array = array.select.with_index { |_, index| index.positive? }
```

```
# Array#select!

array.select!.with_index { |_, index| index.positive? }
```

I'm sure there are many other methods

Please look in the docs to explore it:

https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html

Comment: Two more: `array.replace(array[1..-1])` (mutating) and `_,*a = array`, `a` being the new array (non-mutating).